# Как заменить первые два слова в строке?

Tags: строки, ios, swift, tableview

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Есть два котроллера (FirstVC и SecondVC);
2. На обоих котроллерах таблица;
3. Данные в ячейки первой таблицы вносятся из третьего контроллера, где располагается соответствующие textFieldы. Данные в ячейках второй таблицы не важны (добавил просто для примера).
4. Над второй таблицей (которая на SecondVC) есть UIView, в котором два UILabel. Первый UILabel статичный (там просто слово «СПИСОК»), его значение меняться не будет. Второй UILabel (прямо под первым) – динамичный. Там заданный текст с интерполяцей строк (string interpolation) – “участников (adjustedEventNameText)”
5. Сам adjustedEventNameText задан для того, чтобы выводить названия ячеек из первого контроллера в tableHeaderView на втором контроллере с правильными склонениями на русском языке. К примеру «Соревнование по легкой атлетике» должно преобразовываться в «соревнованиЯ по легкой атлетике». Эта интерполяция во втором стринге идет сразу после слова «участников» и, таким образом, финально получается «СПИСОК участников соревнования по легкой атлетике».

Кстати, если кто-то знает более удачный способ как обходить склонения и окончания, предлагайте пожалуйста, иначе код очень захламлен.

Единичные первые слова я нашел как склонять. А вот когда идет заданное словосочетание, типа «Благотворительное соревнование», я не знаю, как обрабатывать сразу два слова в начале стринга. Помогите пожалуйста.

Вот код второго котроллера:

```
import UIKit

class SecondVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var names: [Cell2Model] = []

var textForChanging: String = ""

var switchedFirstWord: String {
    switch textForChanging.firstWord {
    case "Соревнование": return "соревнования"
    default: return "none" } }

var restoOfTheName: String {
    var string = textForChanging
    string.enumerateSubstrings(in: string.startIndex..., options: .byWords) { (_, _, enclosingRange, stop) in
        string.removeSubrange(enclosingRange)
        stop = true }
    return string }

var adjustedEventNameText: String {
    return switchedFirstWord + " " + restoOfTheName }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    
    // names будут браться из UITextField на четвертом контроллере
    names = [
        (Cell2Model(name: "Иванов")),
        (Cell2Model(name: "Петров")),
        (Cell2Model(name: "Сидоров")) ]
    
    let tableHeader = UIView()
    tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeader
    
    let labelOne = UILabel(frame: tableHeader.bounds)
    labelOne.text = "СПИСОК"
    labelOne.font = UIFont(name:"Arial-BoldMT", size: 17.0)
    labelOne.numberOfLines = 0
    labelOne.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    labelOne.textAlignment = .center
    labelOne.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    let labelTwo = UILabel(frame: tableHeader.bounds)
    labelTwo.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    labelTwo.text = "участников \(adjustedEventNameText)"
    labelTwo.font = UIFont(name:"Arial-BoldMT", size: 17.0)
    labelTwo.numberOfLines = 0
    labelTwo.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    labelTwo.textAlignment = .center
    labelTwo.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    tableHeader.addSubview(labelOne)
    tableHeader.addSubview(labelTwo)

    let g = tableHeader.layoutMarginsGuide
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        labelOne.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 11.0),
        labelOne.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
        labelOne.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
        labelTwo.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelOne.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        labelTwo.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
        labelTwo.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0), ])
    
    let c = labelTwo.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -11.0)
    c.priority = .required - 1
    c.isActive = true
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if let tableHeader = tableView.tableHeaderView {
        let fitSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: tableView.frame.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let sz: CGSize = tableHeader.systemLayoutSizeFitting(fitSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority: .required, verticalFittingPriority: .defaultLow)
        let height: CGFloat = sz.height
        var headerFrame = tableHeader.frame
        if height != headerFrame.size.height {
            headerFrame.size.height = height
            tableHeader.frame = headerFrame
            tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeader } } }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return names.count }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "secondCell", for: indexPath) as! SecondCell
    let Name = names[indexPath.row]
    cell.label.text = Name.name
    return cell } }

extension StringProtocol {
var byWords: [SubSequence] { components(separated: .byWords) }

func components(separated options: String.EnumerationOptions)-> [SubSequence] {
    var components: [SubSequence] = []
    enumerateSubstrings(in: startIndex..., options: options) { _, range, _, _ in components.append(self[range]) }
    return components }

var firstWord: SubSequence? {
    var word: SubSequence?
    enumerateSubstrings(in: startIndex..., options: .byWords) { _, range, _, stop in
        word = self[range]
        stop = true }
    return word } }
```

А также, для целостного понимания, код первого контроллера:

```
import UIKit

class FirstVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var names: [Cell1Model] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    
    // names будут браться из UITextField на третьем контроллере
    names = [
        Cell1Model(name: "Соревнование по легкой атлетике"),
        Cell1Model(name: "Благотворительное соревнование по легкой атлетике")
    ]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as? SecondVC {
        vc.textForChanging = names[indexPath.row].name!
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true) } }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return names.count }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
    let Name = names[indexPath.row]
    cell.label.text = Name.name
    return cell }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

А вопрос в чем? Как склонять >1 слов написанных кириллицей? Если да, то тогда можешь через stringsdict [локализацию](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/localizing-strings-that-contain-plurals) сделать. То есть у тебя будет ключ и таблица со всеми вариантами склонений.

вот пример по первой ссылке в гугле как можно сделать

https://medium.com/@vitaliikuznetsov/plurals-localization-using-stringsdict-in-ios-a910aab8c28c

Comment: Вы бы не могли показать пример? Насколько я понял, в этом случае проверяется вся строка. А если нужно проверить всего два первых слова? Вдруг слова "благотворительное соревнование" применяются далее по строке не единожды?